# How to Delete Service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, service, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, minikube

I executed this command: $ kubectl get services -n demo1

It returned this list of services

LIST OF SERVICES

Please tell me how to delete this service

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To delete your service `my-service` in the namespace `demo1`, you can run :

```
kubectl delete services my-service -n demo1
```